# "Computer Browser" service on Windows Server 2003 crashing server

Tags: windows-service

Our server (a Dell, that matters, since Auto Recovery on our backplate is causing the computer to reboot automatically due to the hang) is running Windows Server 2003 (x86).

Our Browser (aka Computer Browser) service is causing a hang and crash, periodically, almost daily.

I wasn't involved in the setup of the box, but I've never seen this service crash before, and with such regularity. AV is fine, all updates and patches, as well as all firmware is completely up to date.

The box is in a rack with another box, on the same workgroup, connected via 1Gig network.

The system error before the crash is:

> The browser service has failed to
>   retrieve the backup list too many
>   times on transport
>   \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{A544FC1A-2DE6-4EDE-8AA2-120D6D161000}.
>   The backup browser is stopping.

I can't just stop/uninstall this service can I? 
What might the issue be? I need pointing in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually safe to stop/disable the browser service, however sometimes it is better to leave it running, but that depends upon your configuration.

You do state that your server is in a workgroup however, so I can assume it isn't a domain controller.

I'd suggest disabling the service and monitoring the results. If it stabilises your server and doesn't have an adverse effect on your network, then great, problem solved, otherwise you may need to revisit the problem.